# Flexbox not expanding with content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I am trying to build a basic messenger view on a mobile screen. So there is a header at the top, a scrollable list of messages in the middle, and a bar at the bottom with a textarea and button to send a new message.

I am using an autosize plugin to makes the textarea expand as a user types their message. The problem is that as it changes the height property, it will start to overflow the height of the container that it is in, instead of that container expanding to take up more room.

A working sample is here: https://codepen.io/jwynveen/pen/RJdWLB?editors=1100#0

[image]

```css
#container {
  width: 412px;
  height: 660px;
  border: solid 2px black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#container h1 {
  border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
}
#container #message-list {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
#container #message-list .message {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
#container #message-input-bar {
  display: block;
}
#container #message-input {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  border-top: solid 2px red;
}
#container #message-input textarea {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="container">
  <h1>My Header</h1>
  <div id="message-list">
    <div class="message">This is a dummy message.</div>
    <div class="message">This is a dummy message.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="message-input">
    <textarea style="height: 100px"></textarea>
    <button id="send">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

If there are no messages in the center area, the textarea makes its container expand as expected. But once the center area has enough to scroll, the textarea starts to overflow.

Comment: Really weird code - are you simulating the mobile viewport with all these static height/widths?

Comment: You can easily just dock the message box with a `position: fixed` + `bottom: 0` if it's a true, full viewport answer you're looking for. The reason things are goofy right now is the faux viewport you've added in.

Comment: Sorry for the static height/width on the container. Yes, I'm simulating a mobile viewport.

@staypuftman If I use a fixed position div, I then need a dynamic amount of padding on the message list since the #message-input container is now above the message list, right? Otherwise the user can't see the last messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a fix based on the suggestion by @vaishali-kapadia. I wrapped the #message-input with another div so that the added div is `display:block` and the existing one maintains the flexbox layout.

Changed from:

```
<div id="message-input">
  <textarea style="height: 100px"></textarea>
  <button id="send">Send</button>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div id="message-input-bar">
  <div id="message-input">
    <textarea style="height: 100px"></textarea>
    <button id="send">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the added CSS (though not necessary since the div is `display:block` by default):

```
#message-input-bar {
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Solution 1**

You have applied manual height to container. so it stops there after reaching that particular height.

Instead apply **`height: auto;`** so that container can expand as per the content

**See this codepen** - 
https://codepen.io/vaishalik3/pen/QxoyMd?editors=1100#0

> **Solution 2** -
>   In case you want scrollbar as it is.

- Apply **`display: block;`** instead of `flex` to **`#message-input`**
- **`width: 100%;`** or as per your need to **`textarea`**

**See this codepen** - https://codepen.io/vaishalik3/pen/ERMPLd?editors=1100#0

> **Solution 3**

- Apply `display: grid;` to `.container`
- `display: flex;` to  `#message-input`

**See this codepen** - https://codepen.io/vaishalik3/pen/RJdqzq?editors=1100#0

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Solution 2 makes some sense, but I would like the send button to float on the right of the text area. However, the width of different users' screens will differ, so how can I consistently size the textarea width with a statically-sized (48px) icon/button to the right of it?

Comment: codepen updated. please check https://codepen.io/vaishalik3/pen/ERMPLd?editors=1100#0

Comment: That seems to be a decent workaround, but with different viewport sizes, the button won't always be 16% of the width. I'd really like to get the flexbox layout working since it would size the textarea width exactly across viewports. I don't know why the height of that flexbox won't adjust correction though.

Comment: @jwynveen check another method... solution 3 added

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
style="height: 100px"
```

from your textarea and provide height:100% to CSS.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRPQBX?editors=1100#0

Comment: I am using Autosize (https://www.npmjs.com/package/autosize) to set that height so that it expands as users enter more text. With just 100%, it doesn't expand with longer text.